# AWS API Gateway Service Proxy to Kinesis Firehose

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-api-gateway, amazon-kinesis, amazon-kinesis-firehose

Can anyone tell me if there is currently an option to bind the Kinesis Firehose delivery stream to an API Gateway Endpoint via Service Proxy.  I attempting to do it using the Kinesis service type with the Firehose PutRecord action and the new PutRecordRequest json but the gateway failed specifying errors that it was trying to map the incoming request model to the regular kinesis PutRecordRequest model.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Kinesis Firehose support is available in the AWS API Gateway Console as of yesterday.

Answer (score 4):

If you are calling Kinesis firehose from API Gateway, the service type should be firehose and then you can give the PutRecord command which invokes firehose.

Here are the different kinesis services that are mapped in API.

**AWS Service in API Gateway**   --->               **Respective application**

Kinesis     --->                                            Kinesis Streams

Firehose    --->                                            Kinesis Firehose

Kinesis Analytics   --->                                    Kinesis Analytics

Thanks & Regards,
Srivignesh KN

Comment: OMG! Firehose was the name! Thank you so much.